# Why can I listen on an IP not listed by ifconfig?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ifconfig

I'm putting my hands on a legacy system (a Xen cluster) and I'm trying to understand its architecture. It seems that there are services listening on an IP (say, 1.2.3.4) that doesn't show up in `ifconfig` output:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:98:46:4b  
          inet addr:3.3.3.3  Bcast:3.3.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe98:464b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2701271309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2580523122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2013971483375 (1.8 TiB)  TX bytes:1994970579127 (1.8 TiB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:98:46:4b  
          inet addr:10.0.5.4  Bcast:10.0.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12776938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12776938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2103144670 (1.9 GiB)  TX bytes:2103144670 (1.9 GiB)
```

If I have `nc` listen on the IP 1.2.3.4, it is reachable by the outside:

```
nc -s 1.2.3.4 -p 8081 -l
```

(i.e. I can telnet or `nc` to 1.2.3.4:8081 and send data).

This leads me to the conclusion that there's no NAT. However, why doesn't `ifconfig` list the IP?

Comment: From **where** can you telnet to 1.2.3.4:8081?  From on the system itself, or from another system?

Comment: if you want to identify what is listening you can use the -p option of netstat, e.g. netstat -lp

Comment: @MadHatter, I tried connecting from both the same system and another one. – @Jason Tan, that's where I discovered that I had a daemon listening on that address. I was actually asking *why* `ifconfig` doesn't list it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen cases where `ifconfig` doesn't show all of the addresses assigned to an interface, but they can be seen with `ip addr` (where `ip` is from the `iproute2` package).

Comment: You're right. `ip addr` lists that address under eth0, as well as other ones. This confirmed that the system is actually bound to that address. With further investigation I discovered that there is a `keepalived` daemon managing the assignment of the address. You didn't answer to my question (why ifconfig doesn't list all IPs), however your answer helped me a little by confirming that my assumption was right.

Answer (score 1):

```
     -s hostname/ip-address
             Specifies the IP of the interface which is used to send the pack-
             ets.  On some platforms, this can be used for UDP spoofing by
             using ifconfig(8) to bring up a dummy interface with the desired
             source IP address.
```

```
$ nc -s 1.2.3.4 -p 8081 -l &
Can't grab 1.2.3.4:8081 with bind : Cannot assign requested address
```

Perhaps if you run `ifconfig` from another terminal session *whilst* `nc` is still running, you might see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! I tried what you suggested but `ifconfig` still doesn't show that IP.